# Find the set of points in euclidian and taxicab metric that are the same distance from $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

Find the set of points in euclidian and taxicab metric that are the same distance from A = $(0,1)$ and B =$(1,0)$.

So I just started doing metric spaces and I have got to this simple problem.

My understanding:

We can define a metric as:

$$d((x_1,x_2,...,x_n),(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)) = [\sum_{i=1}^{p}|x_i-y_i|^{1/p}]^p $$ , where if $p = 1$ we call it taxicab metric and if $p  = 2$ we call it euclidian metric.

However for this problem I do not know how to begin it. Do I have to look the taxicab metric as only in $\mathbb{R^1}$ space and thus we have a point $x_1 = 1$ and a point $y_1 = 0$ and then for euclidian metric as in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0$ and $y_1 = 0, y_2 = 1$ .

My question is how to go about problems like these?

Comment: Start with the obvious solutions (0,0) and (1,1) and show there aren't any others.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: There are plenty others. For example $(t,t)$ works under both metrics for every $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: OP (@VLC), I think you might be led astray by a typo in the definition -- the summation should be $\sum_{i=1}^n$ rather than $\sum_{i=1}^p$. The dimension is independent of with $p$ you use, so both Euclidean and taxicab/Manhattan metric can work for $\mathbb R^2$. Taxicab is then just $$ d_1((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = |x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$$ or -- with perhaps more intuitive variable names -- $$ d_1((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B)) = |x_A-x_B|+|y_A-y_B|$$

Comment: @Troposphere The original question is somewhat ambiguous.  My interpretation is that both metrics would give the same distances, i.e. $d_t(p.A)=d_e(p.A)$ and $d_t(p.B)=d_e(p.B)$

Comment: @herbsteinberg: Not quite. For exampe if $P=(5,3)$ then $d_t(P,A)=d_t(P,B)=7$ but $d_e(P,A)=3\sqrt 3$ and $d_e(P,B)=5$.

Comment: @Troposphere That was exactly my point.  Find points that satisfy the condition I described.  That is why I suggested that (0,0) and (1,1) are the only possible points.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: Ah, I see what you mean now, apologies for misunderstanding. I doubt that interpretation is intended, though. It's a lot more enlightening (in the sense of developing one's intuition about metric spaces) to find the points such that $d_t(P,A)=d_t(P,B)$ and discover that they are _not_ just the line $x=y$ (and the solution set is not even a curve locally).

Comment: @Troposphere I see, so $p$ is only the root and the exponent, but the upper bound of summation is $n$. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @VLC: Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1):

These are the points $(x,y)$ such that
$$d((x,y),(0,1))=d((x,y),(1,0).$$
That is, $$|x|+|y-1|=|x-1|+|y|$$